# How can I add class_ to preEscapedToHtml in Haskell Blaze or Hamlet?

Tags: haskell, yesod, hamlet

How can I add a class to a `preEscapedToHtml`?

```
renderHtml $ preEscapedText "<div>a</div>" ! class_ "c"
"<div>a</div>"
```

or to an HTML generated by a hamlet template?

however this works:

```
renderHtml $ H.div "a" ! class_ "c"
"<div class=\"c\">a</div>"
```

Comment: `preEscapedText "<div class=\"c\">a</div>"` doesn't work for you somehow?

Comment: No. It is not dry. I will have to make duplicated functions with just different classes. for example `userPhotoProfile = preEscapedText "<div class="user-photo-profile"><img....`, and  `userPhotoOther = preEscapedText "<div class="user-photo"><img....`  where ... can be something long and repeated.

Comment: Which one are you using, preEscapedToHtml or preEscapedText? In any case, can you not refactor your code to use the `H.div "a" ! class_ "c"` method? That seems much cleaner.

Comment: @ricardos if you want DRY, you can just parametrize it: `mkDiv c = preEscapedText ("<div class=\"" ++ c ++ "\">a</div>")`. The point of `preEscapedText` is that you just give it some text, and it doesn't really know if there are any tags inside it or anything. So naturally it can't do anything about injecting classes.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Not good enough, in some cases I want to add a class, maybe in other case I will need to add some "data-*" attribute or whatever the requirements will be.

Comment: @BjarturThorlacius, that is the current solution, and the question is how to avoid this. But personally I don't find it very attractive. I agree it is type safe, is it? and also editable.

Answer (score 0):

The most accurate type in Blaze for an HTML tag is `Tag`. `H.div` is of that type, is it not? What should `preEscapedText "<title>Example</title><p>HTML document" ! class_ "c"` do anyway? Attributes can only be added to tags, and not to HTML documents or fragments. Thus you should keep your tags with type `Tag` until you've added all attributes you need and are ready to combine multiple tags into a HTML fragment or document. If you need to keep track of multiple nodes you're generating in parallel, you can store them in a list, tuple or a record while you're modifying them. Then merge then into an `HTML` at the end.

Comment: I think the best solution will be to keep the parent in a tag, and the children in shamlet or preescaped, example: `linkToHello = a ! href "/hello" $ [shamlet| ...|]` so, the inner part will be written in html while the parent is editable.